# Question mark in URL in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When I generate my hyperlink dynamically then I get a question mark added in the URL where does it comes from what is the meaning of it.

```
<li> @Html.ActionLink(@genre.Name, "Browse", new { genre = genre.Name })</li>

 http://localhost:26239/Store/Browse?genre=Disco
```

Comment: Because your adding a value to the route using `new { genre = genre.Name }`. And because you do not have a route defined for a parameter named `genre` = i.e. `{controller}/{action}/{genre}` it is added as a query string parameter, not a route parameter. If you did have a route defined it would be generated as `.../Store/Browse/Disco`

Answer (score 2):

If "genre" is not defined in the route that matches the action method as a parameter, it will be passed as query string.

Answer (score 2):

There is typical example. We have one route for BookDetail:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "BookDetail",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Book", action = "Detail", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**First example** - with one parameter `id` defined in route rule

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Detail", new { id = item.Id })</li>

http://localhost:26239/Book/Detail/221
```

**Second example** - with another parameter `xy` not defined in route

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Detail", new { id = item.Id, xy = item.Xy })</li>

http://localhost:26239/Book/Detail/221?xy=SomeValue
```

**Third example** - without parameters (because `id` is optional)

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Detail")</li>

http://localhost:26239/Book/Detail
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called a [query parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).  It's a very common way to pass variables in the URL.